# "Window Buttons" panel item on Xfce isn't showing anything at all

Tags: xfce, panel

I recently installed the Xfce desktop environment on my Fedora 32 Linux system to try out if it's any better than Cinnamon.

Everything else seems to work straight out of the box, but there is one problem. The Xfce panel has "panel items" that can be added or removed, and one of them is "Window Buttons", which apparently should show small buttons of every window I have open on the desktop, so I can click on them to switch between the windows.

Except this "Window Buttons" panel isn't showing anything at all. It takes over two-thirds of the horizontal screen estate of the panel, and all of that is just a blank grey slate. There are no buttons, no text, nothing to click on.

What is going on here and how can I fix this?

Comment: It appears that this depends on which panel I am using the item on. On panel #0 (the default panel) the item refuses to work, even if it's the only panel I have. But if I add another panel #1, it works all OK on that panel.

Comment: As a practical matter, it sounds like your problem's solved. It's nevertheless interesting. Using XFCE (version 4.14) on Fedora 31, I have the "Window Buttons" item on Panel 0 and it works fine. The problem might be something to do with the Panel 0 settings; with F32; or, if you happen to be using an [Xfce 4.16 prerelease](https://andreldm.com/2020/09/12/xfce4.16pre1.html), with XFCE itself.

Comment: I am running Xfce 4.14, not 4.16. I always use the latest stable versions, never the development versions, because even though they are more recent, they are less stable.
It might be because I am using Fedora 32 and not Fedora 31. I upgrade the operating system to a new version so seldom that I always upgrade to the latest stable version.

Comment: I just tested adding yet another panel, panel #2. Sure enough, Window Buttons works OK there too. It's just the default panel #0 where it refuses to work. Might it have something to do with that the default panel #0 is narrower vertically than all the other panels?

Comment: I just shrunk my panel #0 down as small as it would go (16 pixels) and the Window Buttons were still there and worked ok, so I doubt narrowness of the panel is the cause.

Comment: Incidentally, it seems possible to make the Window Buttons disappear by setting the panel's "Length (%)" to 1, but you'd probably notice it set so low, so I doubt that's the cause.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue on 20.04

I've deleted Panel 0 and added new one and readded items that were there, and it works.
Optionally create new panel, add items and then delete faulty panel.

A bit annoying, though.